# Python module import not recognising functions

Tags: python, python-import

I've been trying this for a few days without success. I've searched for, and read, many questions and answers here and elsewhere but am still scratching my head.  I'm an experienced programmer but new to Python.

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

I've created a simple module to import which contains 1 function:

```python
def dd_print_func( par ):
   print ("Hello : ", par)
   return
```

I'm importing this into another module as shown here:

```python
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction

try:
    print("import start")
    import dd_file_handler
    print("import end\n")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("import fail 1\n")
except ImportError:
    print("import fail 2\n")
except:
    print("import fail 3\n")
else:
    print("Import worked\n\n")

print("before show functions imported")
print(getmembers(dd_file_handler, isfunction))
print("after show functions imported\n\n")

dd_file_handler.dd_print_func("Zara")
print("finished\n")
```

Here is the output I get when running the second module.
It imports the dd_file_handler module without a reported error.
The print(getmembers(dd_file_handler, isfunction)) shows only [].
Finally the call to dd_file_handler.dd_print_func fails and crashes the program.

```
import start
import end

Import worked


before show functions imported
[]
after show functions imported


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jason\Downloads\my_python_code\test_import_file_handler.py", line 21, in <module>
    dd_file_handler.dd_print_func("Zara")
AttributeError: module 'dd_file_handler' has no attribute 'dd_print_func'
```

Comment: After the import successfully completes, what is the output of `print(dir(dd_file_handler))`?

Comment: Can you do `print(dd_file_handler.__file__) ` to see which file is loaded and confirm it is the one you expect?

Comment: And by the way, the bare `return` is redudnant

Comment: Hi.
welcome to StackOverflow.
I suggest you to have a look at the StackOverflow pinciples on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your questions for the future!
I suggest you improve the question structure focusing quickly on your needs and issues, not writing a preliminary presentation or similar.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're not importing what you think you are. Ive copy pasted your code and it works.

my directory structure is:

```
stackOverflow/
--- main.py
--- dd_file_handler.py
```

in `main.py`:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction

try:
    print("import start")
    import dd_file_handler
    print("import end\n")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("import fail 1\n")
except ImportError:
    print("import fail 2\n")
except:
    print("import fail 3\n")
else:
    print("Import worked\n\n")

print("before show functions imported")
print(getmembers(dd_file_handler, isfunction))
print("after show functions imported\n\n")

dd_file_handler.dd_print_func("Zara")
print("finished\n")
```

in `dd_file_handler.py`

```
def dd_print_func( par ):
   print ("Hello : ", par)
   return
```

run command:

```
\stackOverflow> python main.py
```

output:

```
import start                                               
import end                                                 
                                                           
Import worked                                              
                                                           
                                                           
before show functions imported                             
[('dd_print_func', <function dd_print_func at 0x03485D30>)]
after show functions imported
                             
                             
('Hello : ', 'Zara')         
finished
```

after the import of `dd_file_handler` check that youre importing the right file with: `dd_file_handler.__file__`:

```
    print("import start")
    import dd_file_handler
    print(dd_file_handler.__file__)
    print("import end\n")
```

should print `/stackOverflow/dd_file_handler.py` or you've edited the `dd_file_handler.py` file and forgot to save it xD